# finding something with git

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find the total number of git lines contributed (aka that has made it to stable) by a author, in a project.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you're looking for

```
def lines_of_code_changed(start_date, end_date)
  PullRequest.where(
    author_op_id: operator_id,
    modified_at: start_date..end_date.end_of_day,
    open_ind: false,
    merged_ind: true).sum(:lines_changed)
end
```